# How to format text in discord.js embed with if it has let desc = `text`;

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this embed, created in discord.js, and I want to add code markdown format like `Lorem Ipsum` in the description(s) but I can't do that because of the Grave Accents as it would be (``Lorem Ipsum``) because of the "let desc =`raw text not in code format`", I'm a noob tbh It's probably very easy but I can't figure it out ngl.

Here's my embed:
(My Problem is at lines 9, 12 and 13)

```js
01    if(args[0] === settings.prefix + "help" || args[0] === settings.prefix + "h"){
02        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
03        if(settings.embedColor){
04            embed.setColor(settings.embedColor);
05        }
06        if(settings.embedThumbnail){
07            embed.setThumbnail(settings.embedThumbnail);
08        }
09        let desc = `text`;
10            
11        if(msg.member.hasPermission("SEND_MESSAGES")){
12            desc += `text`
13            desc += `text`
14        }
15        embed.setDescription(desc);
16        msg.channel.send(embed);
17    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 2 methods here:

#1: Don't use backticks for all strings. It's suggested. only use `` `foo` `` when you need to (for templating)

OR

#2: Escape the `` ` ``: `\`this is code\``

Answer (score 0):

You can escape back tics if you choose to use them

```
let rawText = `\`Block Text\``;
```

Or use single/double quotes.

```
let rawText = "`Block Text`";
let rawText2 = '`Block Text`';
```

[Additional Information About Escaping](https://www.afterhoursprogramming.com/tutorial/javascript/backslash-characters/)